# Regular Expressions Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to validate email addresses to my vb.net windows form application,this is the validate email function written in another class

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean

    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"

    If Regex.IsMatch(strEmailAddress, pattern) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

I then called the IsValid function from another class by writing this code

```
 If ValidateEmailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Email Valid")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Email Not Valid")
    End If
```

On-Stepping throught this code,it skips past the Return True statement in the ValidateEmailAddress function an also skips the    MessageBox.Show("Email Valid") in the isValid() function. therefore i get an Email not Valid return statement even wwhen i enter the correct email format. Please is the regex pattern correct or can anyone spot anything im doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a Regex problem. Try this one:

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim EmailRegex As New Regex("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
    If EmailRegex.IsMatch(strEmailAddress) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Sorry for brief answer, at the moment I have very little time to point out where the error may be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will test it now and let you know the result.

Comment: it is still not working, i also changed the regex to be this                                           ("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$")